# How to Add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Header in Java RESTful Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have created one java RESTful web service which is working fine in localhost. But when I try to test it in Dev environment after deploying it on the server, its throwing the following error :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8443/RESTfulWS/rest/UserInfoService/NLP/Mumbai%20is%20the%20financial%20capital%20of%20India?xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://hpscrmdev.honeywell.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I understand that I need to set some header for the resource (i.e the web service) to be accessible from a particular domain, but I am not sure how to implement that. I don't know if I am making sense here as I am a newbie in developing web service. Below is the following code of the web service.

```
package com.eviac.blog.restws;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

// @Path here defines class level path. Identifies the URI path that 
// a resource class will serve requests for.
@Path("UserInfoService")
public class UserInfo {
private static final String plain = null;
// @GET here defines, this method will method will process HTTP GET requests.
@GET
// @Path here defines method level path. Identifies the URI path that a
// resource class method will serve requests for.
@Path("/name/{i}")
// @Produces here defines the media type(s) that the methods
// of a resource class can produce.
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
// @PathParam injects the value of URI parameter that defined in @Path
// expression, into the method.
    public String userName(@PathParam("i") String i) {
    String name = i;
    return "<User>" + "<Name>" + name + "</Name>" + "</User>";
    }

@GET 
@Path("/age/{j}") 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String userAge(@PathParam("j") int j) {

    int age = j;
    return "<User>" + "<Age>" + age + "</Age>" + "</User>";
    }

@GET 
@Path("/NLP/{k}")

@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String nlpPOS(@PathParam("k") String k) {

    String description = k;
    POSTagger obj = new POSTagger();
    ArrayList<String> list = obj.tagging(description);

    String[] result = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

    String resultXML = "<result>";
        for (String s : result) {
            resultXML = resultXML + "<noun>" + s + "</noun>"; 
        }
        resultXML = resultXML + "</result>";

        return resultXML;
    }
}
```

I am using only the nlpPOS method. I also have another class which contains the tagging() method for performing the web service. Can anybody help me where to set the header in this code?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!!
Chiranjit

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation and version are you using?

Comment: CORS is handled through HTTP headers, so whatever way you manipulate HTTP headers works. Example: a simple filter which your server may have built-in. For example Tomcat has it: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Comment: @ peeskillet : the version is 1.17.1. BTW what do you mean by JAX-RS implementation?

Comment: @ Gimby: Thanks for ur response. We have deployed the web service in Weblogic server, do you have any idea on weblogic?

Comment: I would effectively be copy/pasting urls I found in literally less than half a minute with Google. I urge you to type in "weblogic cors" yourself. "jax-rs add http header" also returns many interesting existing stackoverflow questions with answers.

Comment: Hi Gimby, After searching on the net, I was able to put the header using filter class, but the following error came up: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/RESTfulWS] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;  Would you please help me find out which jar to be used if this is issue with the version?  
Thanks!!